# Postgres balanceamento de carga servidores Windows

Tags: postgresql, balanceamento-carga

Estou querendo saber um pouco mais sobre balanceamento de carga no Postgres e um pouco de failover.
Vi em vários sites inclusive no Postgres que existe um programa chamado pgpool i e ii, este programa faz o balanceamento e também trata o failover. Porém o danado é só para Linux.

Alguém já viu ou já fez algo para Servidores Windows, se sim pode passar o link com conteúdo ou explicar mais ou menos?

Valeu